# Multiple Task Continuation - wait until all complete

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following piece of code whereby I first run a query and add the raw results `ViewModel.RawContracts.AddRange(contractResults);`

I then want to enrich this set of data with multiple different data sources e.g. `_enrichmentHelper.ResolveSecurities(token, contractsToEnrich);` all of the enrichment within these methods are themselves done asynchronously.

Once all this enrichment has been completed I want to run a final piece of code to take the now enriched raw data to add it to my grid `ViewModel.ContractRows.AddRange(ViewModel.RawContracts);`

However my final Continuation `queryAndEnrichmentTask` is executing once the query task completes rather than after each of the enrichment continuations complete.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew
(
    () =>
    {
        Log.Debug("Starting getting contracts");
        Task queryTask = _serviceModel.GetContractsByCriteriaAsync(token, ViewModel.QueryRequest)
            .LogExceptions()
            .ContinueWith
            (
                prevTask =>
                {
                    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        IQueryResponse response = null;
                        Log.Debug("Received contract response.");

                        if (prevTask.IsFaulted || (response = prevTask.Result) == null)
                        {
                            ViewModel.ErrorMessage = "Failed to load contracts. Please check the log file for details.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (response.Contracts != null)
                            {
                                Log.Debug($"Start loading {response.Contracts.Count()} contract positions...");

                                bool successful = true; 

                                if (successful && prevTask.IsCompleted && prevTask.Result != null)
                                {
                                    contractResults = prevTask.Result.Contracts.ToList();
                                    ViewModel.RawContracts.Clear();
                                    ViewModel.RawContracts.AddRange(contractResults);
                                }
                                Log.Debug("Finished loading contracts");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.Debug("Finished loading contracts");

                }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled, TaskScheduler.Default
            ); // End add raw results task

            IList<IContract> contractsToEnrich = ViewModel.RawContracts;

            queryTask.ContinueWith(prevTask =>
            {
                _enrichmentHelper.ResolveSecurities(token, contractsToEnrich);
            }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);

            queryTask.ContinueWith(prevTask =>
            {
                _enrichmentHelper.ResolveBooks(token, contractsToEnrich);
            }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);

            queryTask.ContinueWith(prevTask =>
            {
                _enrichmentHelper.ResolveCounterparties(token, contractsToEnrich);
            }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);

            queryTask.ContinueWith(prevTask =>
            {
                _enrichmentHelper.ResolveLegalEntities(token, contractsToEnrich);
            }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }, token
)
.LogExceptions()
.ContinueWith
(
    queryAndEnrichmentTask =>
    {
        Log.Debug("Post search task started");

        if (queryAndEnrichmentTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            if (!ViewModel.HasErrorMessage)
                ViewModel.ErrorMessage = "Error occured when loading data. Please refer to log file for details";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewModel.ContractRows.AddRange(ViewModel.RawContracts);
        }
        Log.Debug("Post search task completed");
    }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled, TaskScheduler.Default)
.LogExceptions();
```

Comment: You should rarely, if ever, use `ContinueWith`.  Use `await` to add continuations to tasks.  It's *far* easier to write correctly, and makes it much less likely that you'll have hard to diagnose bugs in your code.  There are very rarely situations where `ContinueWith` is either needed or preferable.

Comment: Disagree with never using `ContinueWith`. Use the convention defined by your team, the library being worked with, and/or your own experience.

Answer (score 1):

You create `queryTask` inside an outer task, but never await it. The outer task will return before queryTask completes.  The `ContinueWith()` on the outer task will run when the outer task returns, and won't wait for `queryTask` to complete.

The smallest fix is to await `queryTask` before ending the task block that contains it. The outer task will still return but its `Task` will be set to an incomplete state, allowing `ContinueWith()` to do its job by awaiting it and then proceeding.

```
    await queryTask;  //<-- add this
)
.LogExceptions()
.ContinueWith
(
    queryAndEnrichmentTask =>
```